# Objects inside array post node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a little problem when I tried to post information on my server (node.js).
My array is:

```
order[0] = {orderID:"0", customerOrderRef:"Mary", albums: { numberOfPhotos: "1", citation:"sing", photo
{photoPath: "here"}, qty: "1"}, deliveryAddress: {street: "poland street",
doorNumber:"100", zipCode:"5555", city:"London", country: "England"}, status: "waiting",
createdOn: now};
```

and when I tried to POST information:

```
.post(function(req, res) {
    console.dir(req.body);
    orderCount++;
    orders[orderCount] =  buildMessage(orderCount,req.body.customerOrderRef,req.body.numberOfPhotos,req.body.citation,req.body.photoPath,req.body.qty,req.body.street,req.body.doorNumber,req.body.zipCode,req.body.country);
    res.status(201).set('Location', SERVER_ROOT + "/PrintingOrder/" + orderCount).json(orders[orderCount]);
    })
```

and my buildmessage function

```
function buildMessage(newID, user, numberOfPhotos, citation, photoPath, qty, street,doorNumber, zipCode,  city, country){
return {
    orderID : newID, 
    customerOrderRef : user,
    numberOfPhotos: numberOfPhotos,
    citation: citation,
    photoPath: photoPath,
    qty: qty,
    street: street,
    doorNumber: doorNumber,
    zipCode: zipCode,
    country: country,
    status: "waiting"
};
};
```

when I tried POST information, this works fine. But, the information doesn't appears with the same nomenclature of the first value in array (Object inside array).

What I expect:

```
{
"orderID": "0",
"customerOrderRef": "Mary",
"albums": {
    "numberOfPhotos": "1",
    "citation": "home sweet home",
    "photo": {
        "photoPath": "here"
    },
    "qty": "1"
},
"deliveryAddress": {
    "street": "street",
    "doorNumber": "100",
    "zipCode": "5555",
    "city": "London",
    "country": "England"
},
"status": "waiting",
"createdOn": "2015-01-02T12:45:35.034Z"
}
```

What I actually obtain:

```
{
"orderID": 1,
"customerOrderRef": "Jane",
"numberOfPhotos": "2",
"citation": "test",
"photoPath": "test",
"qty": "2",
"street": "street",
"doorNumber": "111",
"status": "waiting"
}
```

Comment: Could you post an example of the actual output?

Comment: Also could you post the output you're expecting?

Comment: updated in first post

Comment: Thats what the structure you return from `buildMessage` method.

Comment: yes...but when I try to construct the array like:

orderID : newID, 
customerOrderRef : user,
albums.numberOfPhotos: numberOfPhotos,
albums.citation: citation,
albums.photo.photoPath: photoPath,
albums.qty: qty,
deliveryAddress.street: street,
deliveryAddress.doorNumber: doorNumber,
deliveryAddress.zipCode: zipCode,
deliveryAddress.country: country,
status: "waiting"

Doesn't work.

Comment: You're expecting orderID:0 but sending over newID which is actually (orderCount++) from the calling function.

Comment: The orderID:0 is an example. In this case, I need POST information in that format (equal to orderID 0 format).